# Desktop shortcut to logout from KDE Plasma session

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I type this command

```
qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer logout 0 3 3
```

to logout from my "user" user (it is sudo user with admin rights) in terminal to logout. Can I create a desktop shortcut so that "user" logs out with single click.

For some reason, I have to disable menu. (it is a production server)

So, I can only use terminal command and desktop shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Alt + Del

You can find it in System Settings | Shortcuts